# Is it possible to update a node of an XML column with the value of another node in a separate XML column in SQL2012

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I have two tables: `tags` and `devices`, each of them has XML columns: `tag_config`, `device_config` respectively. I am trying to update the value of one node in the `device_config` XML based on the value of a node in `tag_config`.

I have used the following statement to update a node in `device_config` based on a column of integers:

```
update d
set device_config.modify('replace value of (//plc_int_device_status/text())[1] with sql:column("t.uid")')
from devices d join tags t on 
d.device_name = t.name
```

Is it possible to replace `sql:column("t.uid")` with a query() of the `tag_config` column in order to get the value of a specific node?

Comment: If my XML is up to speed, this should be possible, but you might have to do dynamic SQL to pass the value as a variable.

Comment: You can create a CTE that extracts the value into a column, and then update based on that column. There are a couple of different ways to do this.

Comment: @pmbAustin I was considering something like that, but was hoping there was an XQuery statement that would get the task done. I am a little familiar with at least one way to do this, but my SQL skills are not very great when I stray from what I'm used to.

Comment: @AChrapko The `XQuery` statement lives **within one XML**. It has no knowledge of another XML, just because it is part of the same table...

Answer (score 0):

You can use an *updateable CTE* first to extract the value you need and then to update your other column:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, XML1 XML, XML2 XML);
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
 ('<root><SomeElement test="x">InnerText</SomeElement></root>'
 ,'<root><OtherElement test="y">OtherText</OtherElement></root>'
 )
,('<root><SomeElement test="a">abc</SomeElement></root>'
 ,'<root><OtherElement test="b">xyz</OtherElement></root>'
 );

SELECT XML1 FROM @mockup;

WITH updateableCTE AS
(
    SELECT XML1
          ,XML2.value('(/root/OtherElement/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS NewText
    FROM @mockup 
)
UPDATE updateableCTE
SET XML1.modify('replace value of (/root/SomeElement/text())[1] with sql:column("NewText")');

SELECT XML1 FROM @mockup;
```